# How to prevent a Singleton object from being cloned?

Tags: javascript, singleton, clone

I have implemented the Singleton pattern in the following way:

```
class Singleton {
  static #instance_holder = [];
  constructor() {
    if (0 !== Singleton.#instance_holder.length) return Singleton.#instance_holder[0];
    Singleton.#instance_holder.push(this);
    Object.preventExtensions(this);
    console.log("You'll see me only once, when the object is first instantiated.");
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine as far as regular declaration/assignment is concerned:

```
const s1 = new Singleton();
//OUTPUT: You'll see me only once, when the object is first instantiated.

const s2 = new Singleton(); //no additional instantiation, the existing one is assigned to s2

s1 instanceof Singleton //true
s2 instanceof Singleton //true
s1 === s2 //true
```

However, it is still possible to clone the instance (`s1`) using `Object.create` or `Object.assign` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s1))`.

```
const clone = Object.create(s1);

clone instanceof Singleton //true
clone === s1 //false
```

How can I prevent the object from being cloned in these ways?

Comment: Why is cloning a problem?

Comment: Because then there will be 2 instances of a Singleton, effectively turning it into a Doubleton!

Comment: Who do you want to prevent it from? Let the bad developer mess up their own code, not your problem.

Comment: Sure, but why do you expect your code to randomly clone the object? Surely you have enough control over it to not do that. And I'm not sure why having two of it is an issue, either.

Comment: These are valid objections, but I'm just experimenting to learn. When I make a Singleton, I expect every effort in circumnavigating it to fail (preferably by throwing an exception) regardless of who tries to do it.

Comment: Well, it's not really possible to do that. Even in Java or C# you can use reflection to bypass a singleton. It doesn't make much sense to protect against multiple instances as ultimately they are an inconvenience rather than a problem. If whoever is writing the code wants to be inconvenienced and even spends extra effort to be inconvenienced, then just let them.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth that implementation of a singleton is an overkill. Just use a module and export an instance or a factory (probably if you want a pool). Then there is no need to write code to prevent `new` from working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can't. There isn't a JS mechanism that would prevent cloning.

If it is super important that something be a singleton, it is probably something in that class that you really care about. In that case, it'd be best if you put that something in the global scope and have your class reference it.

```
const data = {};

class Singleton {
  // singleton setup

  doSomething() {
    return data.something();
  }
}
```

This would ensure that even if the singleton was cloned, as long as it is using the same data source, it still acts like a singleton.

That said... I really don't recommend doing this. I can't really think of a circumstance where you'd actually need to enforce a true singleton. If someone does something goofy with their code, that's their problem.